# max function in comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to understand max function in this code. If I use my common sense, I put max function like this k, max(len(v)) instead of below. But this gives me a syntax error. How max function operates in here?

```
animals = { 'a': ['aardvark'], 'b': ['baboon'], 'c': ['coati']}

animals['d'] = ['donkey']
animals['d'].append('dog')
animals['d'].append('dingo')

def biggest(aDict):
    '''
    aDict: A dictionary, where all the values are lists.

    returns: The key with the largest number of values associated with it
    '''
    # List comprehension
    return max((k, len(v)) for k, v in aDict.items())[0]

print(biggest(animals))
```

Comment: It doesn't behave any differently. len returns an int and max(5) doesn't make sense because 5 isn't a collection of numbers that you can get the maximum from. You won't get a syntax error from that though, you'll get a TypeError

Comment: Yeah you are right about len. but animals.items() gives dict_items([('a', ['aardvark']), ('b', ['baboon']), ('c', ['coati']), ('d', ['donkey', 'dog', 'dingo'])]). Why max considers rightside but not left side?

Comment: You shouldn't assume that max will pick the tuple that has a second value with the biggest length - that's incredibly specific. You can use max's `key` parameter to extract the value that the tuples should be compared by.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want the maximum key, but the longest value.
Use the `key` argument of `max`:

```
from operator import itemgetter

animals = {'a': ['aardvark', 'donkey', 'dog'], 'b': ['baboon'], 'c': ['coati']}

def biggest(aDict):
    '''
    aDict: A dictionary, where all the values are lists.

    returns: The key with the largest number of values associated with it
    '''
    # List comprehension
    return max(((k, len(v)) for k, v in aDict.items()), key=itemgetter(1))[0]

print(biggest(animals))
```

Output:

```
a
```

Alternative solution:

```
max(animals.items(), key=lambda item: len(item[1]))[0]
```